# Is this a redundant allocation of memory space in a multi dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

From the [Matrix Chain Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) page on Wikipedia, there is this fragment of Java code:

```
public void matrixChainOrder(int[] p) {
    int n = p.length - 1;
    m = new int[n][n];
    s = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[n];
        m[i][i] = 0;
        s[i] = new int[n];
    }
    ...
```

Isn't `m = new int[n][n];` already allocating memory space of size `n` in both its dimensions so this step in the loop `m[i] = new int[n];` is actually redundant because all it does is reallocate the second dimension again?

Comment: I've removed the redundant code from the article.

Comment: `m[i][i] = 0` doesn't make much sense either, since it only zeros the diagonal.

Comment: No, because the entire array is initialized to contain only zeros to begin with.

Comment: actually I meant to reply to @CodesInChaos, although I admit it was worded a bit poorly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is.

`m[i] = new int[n];` is absolutely superfluous. And it seems that this line is heritage from `c`-style psedocode, where such initilization was nessecary.

Comment: Not only that, so is the entire loop. Java initializes `int[]`s to zero.